# Error when joining path to check if file exists

Tags: python-3.x

Hey I need help to process simulation data

I'm building a function to check what the highest 4 digit named folder in a given path is and if it contains a file named "shearrate". This is done in the directory of the path itself and in every folder in the given path that is not named 4 digits.

The function works fine until I add the check if the file exists.

Would be very grateful if you could help :)

```
def file_filter (folder):
    if folder.isdigit() and len(folder) == 4:
        return True

def scan_directory(path, name):
    folderlist = []
    folder_level_1 = 0
    folder_level_2 = 0

    for folder in os.listdir(path):                                     
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, folder)):                  
            if file_filter(folder) is True:                             
                a_file = Path(os.path.join(path, folder, name))
                if a_file.is_file():
                  if int(folder) > int(folder_level_1):                   
                      folder_level_1 = folder                       
            else:                                                      
                for folder2 in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder)):  
                    if file_filter(folder2) is True:                    
                        a_file = Path(os.path.join(path, folder, name))
                        if a_file.is_file():                            
                            if int(folder2) > int(folder_level_2):      
                                folder_level_2 = folder2

                if file_filter(folder_level_2) is True:
                    folderlist.append(os.path.join(path, folder, folder_level_2))

                folder_level_2 = str(0)

    folderlist.append(os.path.join(path, folder_level_1))
    return folderlist

folderlist = scan_directory(path, "shearrate")
```

The Error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_evaluation.py", line 141, in <module>
    search_files("shearrate", path)
  File "data_evaluation.py", line 107, in search_files
    folderlist = scan_directory(path, name)
  File "data_evaluation.py", line 98, in scan_directory
    folderlist.append(os.path.join(path, folder_level_1))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 94, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/genericpath.py", line 149, in _check_arg_types
    (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'int'
```

`

Comment: "The function works fine until I add the check if the file exists" - what happens then?

Comment: I added the Error

Comment: Well, which one of `path, folder_level_1` can be an integer? I'd guess it's `folder_level_1` because it's been initialized with a zero at the beginning of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error points out join can't take int so you need to change the type of the input variables to str instead:

```
folderlist.append(os.path.join(path, str(folder_level_1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you cast the folder to `int` before calling `join` which expects `string` arguments. Says so in the error message. I'd suggest you print out the value of the variable before you call `os.path.join` on it. Either way casting back to string `str(folder_level_1)`should help.